# Complex Event Processing engines with Go

Tags: go, complex-event-processing

Are there any [CEP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_event_processing) engines available in Go (like [Esper](http://esper.codehaus.org/) for JVM & .Net) to process the time series data?

Answer (score 0):

It’s not yet done and can’t compare to Esper, but my *[Tideland Go Cell Network](https://github.com/tideland/gocells)* is intended for event-driven architectures.
Next parts will be more cell behaviors, distribution and event sourcing for persistency.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

1. [flogo](https://www.flogo.io/) It includes a CEP engine.
2. [go-streams](https://github.com/reugn/go-streams) A lightweight stream processing library for Go with a lightweight CEP engine